# Bundle identifier yourcompany format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I"m trying to upload my app to the app store.  I'm getting bundle Identifier error when using App Loader.  If my company name is "Acme Inc.", what should I replace the "yourcompany" part of the Bundle ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.acmeinc.AppName

It doesn't HAVE to be your company, just something unique that you can remember. The user doesn't see this. It's just for your own reference. com.CompanyName.AppName is pretty unique and specific, right?

Btw, make sure the bundle identifier for your app in iTunes Connect and the one in your app match up. I think that's what your problem is.

Comment: thx.  i think that is my problem now too.  My Bundle ID in iTunes Connect is "AppName" , but as you mentioned should be com.CompanyName.AppName .  Is there a way I can edit this?

Answer (score 0):

yes Bundle identifier looks like com.YourcompanyName.Appname . did u change Info.Plist "Bundle identifier" and Project setting Any IOS these two must be same